# Font inheriting from transition

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make transition stuff by -25 degrees but what i want is to only transit "box", not the font. The thing that i don't understand is how to make it with :before/:after. Whenever i try to do it via CSS it basically ignores all setting i've made for specific container.

```
.option:hover
{
font-style: normal !important;
background-color: green;
cursor: pointer;
box-sizing: border-box;
transition-property: background;
transition-duration: .4s;
left: 0;
top: 0;
-webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3fndahd2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you skew the whole div, which includes anything inside. There's no way to exclude anything.

There are two ways around this:

1. Apply the opposite skew to inner elements, i.e. have an additional container for the text which is skewed the other way around in order to be straight again. I wouldn't do this, because it may lead to a blurry result or artifacts.
2. Use CSS3 pseudo-elements: Create an element using `::before`, give it full parent size and skew this one. It's outside your text, so that's not affected by the transform. In addition, use z-index to place it behind the parent div. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fndahd2/4/)

Comment: Really helpful, gonna try to use both of this options, edit and combine some additional setups to see how it works and analyse mostly behaviour of :before/:after functions! Thanks once again :)